# The requested amz/amazon-pay-module could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name

Tags: installation, magento2

I am trying to install a website from server to localhost. When I run the command composer update in git-bash then I get the following error. Please check the screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmmGY.png)

All the other modules got installed properly only these three are causing issue.
I have checked several threads similar to this issue, found many answers but none worked in my case.

Here is my composer.json file

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.11",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.12",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magepal/magento2-customshippingrate": "^1.3",
    "mestrona/magento-module-categoryredirect": "^2.1",
    "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module": "1.2.5",
    "amzn/login-with-amazon-module": "1.2.5",
    "amzn/amazon-pay-module": "1.2.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

}

If anyone have any idea then please guide me in the right direction. I am really stuck into it.

Answer (score 0):

Please install amz-pay the latest extension which supports php latest version.Instead of, installing from composer please put through files.